# InvalidCastException, fetching enum value from SqlDataReader in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, enums, casting

I am getting a `System.InvalidCastException` at runtime with this code:

```
inf.Country = (Country)(int)rdr["Country"];
```

Model class:

```
public class BasicInfo
{
    .....
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Female
}

public enum Country
{
    Australia,
    Bangladesh,
    England,
    France,
    Usa
}
```

`DbConnect` class: the method return the **entities** list and it will pass through the controller's view.

`usp_GetAllStudentData` is a stored procedure that returns the list of records.

```
public List<BasicInfo> SelectStudent()
{
    ConnectionString();//Contain Connection string
    List<BasicInfo> entities = new List<BasicInfo>();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetAllStudentData", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    conn.Open();

    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(rdr.Read())
    {
        BasicInfo inf = new BasicInfo();
        inf.FirstName = (string)rdr["FirstName"];
        .....//other required value are assigned to class members.
        //inf.Gender = (Gender)(int)rdr["Gender"];
        inf.Country = (Country)(int)rdr["Country"];  // Getting run time exception here 

        entities.Add(inf);
    }

    return entities;
}
```

[How the data is stored in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMMMm.png)

Can you guys let me know what is the best method to cast an enum value?

Or let me know if there is any alternative way to fix this issue.

[Table Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaccw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database field contains a NULL value then the result of your code is the Invalid Cast Exception

For example

```
 object x = DbNull.Value;          // A null value on the db is represented by DbNull.Value
 inf.Country = (Country)(int)x;    // Gives the Invalid Cast Exception
```

How to fix depends on what you want to do with null values. If you don't allow null values for countries then you should revise your code that accepts an invalid input and block these inputs (and not forget to set the Country field to NOT allow NULL values on the database table)

If you accept a null value then I suggest to add another entry to your country enum

```
public enum Country
{
  Australia = 0,
  Bangladesh,
  England,
  France,
  Usa,
  // <=== new countries should be added here....
  Undefined = 9999
}
```

and change your reading code to

```
int ordinal = rdr.GetOrdinal("Country");
inf.Country = rdr.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? Country.Undefined
                                    : (Country)(int)rdr["Country"];
```

From your comments it seems that you have stored the numeric value of the enum in a varchar column transforming your number in a string 
If you want to convert back this string to the appropriate enum value then you should use Enum.TryParse, but the conversion back is not as simple as it seems.

So if you want to still check for null values then:

```
int ordinal = rdr.GetOrdinal("Country");
// Check for null value....
if(rdr.IsDBNull(ordinal))
    inf.Country = Country.Undefined;
else
{
    // OK, not null, but what if it is "ABC"??
    if(!Enum.TryParse(rdr["Country"].ToString(), out inf.Country))
       inf.Country = Country.Undefined;

    // OK, but what if it is a number not defined in the coutry enum (IE "88")
    if(!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Country), inf.Country))
       inf.Country = Country.Undefined;
}
```

As you can see, if there isn't a specific reason then I suggest to store the enum value as an integer and not as a string. This allow more flexibility in your code and in future changes to this variable.

Comment: I have used the accepting null value concept but its given me InvalidCast Exception.

Comment: How is defined the column "Country" on the database table ? I assume that its datatype is Int right?

Comment: No,its a varchar type.

Comment: Updated questions with table design structure.

Comment: But do you want to store the numeric representation of the enum (0,1,2,3) or do you want to store the name of the country?

Comment: as of now, for all records country column contain the (0,1,2) values and column data type is varchar so, i will go with (0,1,2) values for country in the table.

Comment: Then do not use the varchar datatype. You store numbers not characters and this is the reason of all your problems with conversion. There is no implicit conversion from a varchar to an integer. However the TryParse approach will work also with 0,1,2

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if (rdr["Country"]!=DBNull.Value)
 {
 inf.Country  =(Country)Enum.ToObject(typeof(Country) , rdr["Country"].ToString());
 }
```

Comment: Got "The value passed in must be an enum base or an underlying type for an enum" ('System.ArgumentException' ) exception

Comment: The value passed in must be an enum base or an underlying type for an enum, such as an Int32.